# How to check/confirm that client certificate is being sent on a 2-way SSL connection using tcpdump?

Tags: ssl, tcpdump

I am trying to find out if it is possible to confirm or check that a client certificate is being sent (from the client-side) when a 2-way SSL connection is being established, using tcpdump (and if so, how?).  I am trying to do this because we need to validate that a 2-way SSL connection (vs. just a 1-way SSL connection) is actually being established.

In our configuration, the "client side" is an Oracle OAM Apache webgate, and the "server side" is an OAM server.

Connection is from the webgate ==> OAM server, listening on (for example) port 5575.

The connection is established when the webgate processes a request the 1st time, and the connection stays up for awhile after that, so the way I have been testing this is:

- Start up the Apache (the webgate is an Apache module).  At this point there is no connection to the OAM server port 5575.
- Send a request (using a browser) to the Apache.  This causes the webgate to establish a (supposedly 2-way SSL) connection to the OAM server port 5575.

I have been trying various tcpdump command lines (run on the client/webgate machine) to try to show/capture the webgate's client cert, but so far, I have not been able to see any indication that the webgate is sending a client cert.

I am not very familiar with tcpdump, so I was hoping that someone could suggest how to do this.

Thanks!
Jim

EDIT: I hope that this is ok to add on here.  FYI, I have been unable to directly confirm whether 2-way SSL is occurring.  However, I was able to do the following:

- I did some tcpdump captures and read that into ssldump:

```
New TCP connection #2: 192.168.aa.bb(37256) <-> 172.31.xx.yy(5575)
0.0011 (0.0011)  C>S
---------------------------------------------------------------
4e 4d 50 04 01                                     NMP..
---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0034 (0.0022)  S>C
---------------------------------------------------------------
4e 4d 50 05 01                                     NMP..
---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0035 (0.0001)  C>S
---------------------------------------------------------------
00 00 00 34 00 00 00 00 00 0d 70 72 6f 74 6f 63    ...4......protoc
6f 6c 3d 4e 41 50 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 34    ol=NAP version=4
20 6f 6c 64 65 73 74 3d 31 20 63 6d 3d 6a 6c 74     oldest=1 cm=jlt
65 73 74 31                                        est1
---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0052 (0.0017)  S>C
---------------------------------------------------------------
00 00 00 3e 00 00 00 00 00 0d 70 72 6f 74 6f 63    ...>......protoc
6f 6c 3d 4e 41 50 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 35    ol=NAP version=5
20 6f 6c 64 65 73 74 3d 31 20 63 6c 69 65 6e 74     oldest=1 client
5f 6e 61 70 5f 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 34          _nap_version=4
---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0054 (0.0001)  C>S
---------------------------------------------------------------
00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 01 00 73 74 73 3d 63 65    ..........sts=ce
72 74                                              rt
---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0097 (0.0043)  S>C
---------------------------------------------------------------
00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 01 00 73 74 73 3d 63 65    ..........sts=ce
72 74                                              rt
---------------------------------------------------------------

2 1  0.0106 (0.0008)  C>S V3.3(81)  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3
        random[32]=
          61 08 bc db 2a 3d e1 ac 7e fc e4 c8 cb 34 8b d4
          65 f5 35 bc 31 89 d4 4b 99 5f 3b 22 f5 5a 67 bf
        cipher suites
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
        compression methods
                  NULL
        extensions
          signature_algorithms
        ja3 string: 771,53-10-255,13,,
        ja3 fingerprint: 9331064077bda87e0c2780d544d22b00
2 2  0.0128 (0.0022)  S>C V3.3(2041)  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.3
        random[32]=
          13 c8 0a 1c 90 28 eb 39 55 b0 2f 55 ba 33 b1 9b
          7b 45 f6 be 20 33 13 fa 44 4f 57 4e 47 52 44 01
        session_id[32]=
          0d 07 2d cf c8 a3 90 27 22 70 6b 5c cf e0 1d 36
          f1 6c af 88 59 5f 74 1a 9b 35 df e8 e6 f8 da 78
        cipherSuite         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        compressionMethod                   NULL
        extensions
          renegotiation_info
        ja3s string: 771,53,65281
        ja3s fingerprint: 7b6819ed58e8d8415604b7dfcef92d55
      Certificate
      ServerHelloDone
2 3  0.0136 (0.0007)  C>S V3.3(262)  Handshake
      ClientKeyExchange
        EncryptedPreMasterSecret[256]=
          31 aa 1d a9 63 5c ff f8 29 0b 24 5d 7e ee 98 ff
          cf 25 94 2f 55 5d 48 91 c1 67 c4 ea 39 71 7e ce
          3c a6 a7 18 2c 3d f5 a4 07 1f 54 1e 01 82 b3 7b
          46 fe 46 90 25 79 b2 46 5e 03 c3 4f df 81 89 d7
.
.
.
          b5 e8 44 d5 cd 92 02 82 f3 42 27 56 5d 23 5b c1
          9a e8 8e ec 4b 35 e8 4e 57 01 cb bc 61 09 66 c0
          5c 8d 20 47 b4 da ef 2d 25 71 c8 7f 73 3b 47 7a
          43 04 0b 6d 27 b3 c3 af 17 89 af d9 04 c1 66 a1
2 4  0.0136 (0.0000)  C>S V3.3(1)  ChangeCipherSpec
2 5  0.0136 (0.0000)  C>S V3.3(64)  Handshake
2 6  0.0165 (0.0029)  S>C V3.3(1)  ChangeCipherSpec
2 7  0.0565 (0.0400)  S>C V3.3(64)  Handshake
2 8  0.0567 (0.0002)  C>S V3.3(96)  application_data
2 9  0.0589 (0.0021)  S>C V3.3(160)  application_data
2 10 0.0591 (0.0002)  C>S V3.3(96)  application_data
2 11 0.0615 (0.0023)  S>C V3.3(144)  application_data
2 12 0.0617 (0.0001)  C>S V3.3(528)  application_data
2 13 0.1017 (0.0400)  C>S V3.3(80)  application_data
2 14 0.1042 (0.0025)  S>C V3.3(1296)  application_data
2 15 0.1116 (0.0074)  C>S V3.3(288)  application_data
2 16 0.1145 (0.0028)  S>C V3.3(352)  application_data
2 17 0.1179 (0.0034)  C>S V3.3(64)  application_data
2 18 0.1205 (0.0026)  S>C V3.3(336)  application_data
2 19 4.6999 (4.5793)  C>S V3.3(1664)  application_data
2 20 4.7183 (0.0184)  S>C V3.3(1296)  application_data
Cleaned 5 remaining connection(s) from connection pool
```

Notice in the above that there is no CertificateRequest, etc.

- I did some additional "openssl s_client" connection tests, and it appears that there is no "list of acceptable CAs" sent by the server-side during the SSL handshake.

So I was wondering if:  Would the above 2 pieces of information seem to imply that there was no 2-way SSL connection being established?

Comment: Do you control the server? If so you can enable client authentication which means the server will abort the TLS handshake if the client does not send a certificate when requested to do so, or when the certificate given is not compatible with the rules in place at the server. Other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Using tcpdump (or simpler with a GUI: wireshark) may not yield what you need, especially with TLS 1.3 where almost all parts of the exchanges will be encrypted, including steps at the beginning of the handshake. But otherwise, the server would sent a CertificateRequest/CertificateVerify TLS packet, to which the client should reply with a Certificate. But again, things are far simpler if controlling the server and having access to its logs, just look at that, no need to sniff the network.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek+ in 1.2 and below server doesn't send CertVerify (and if it did it wouldn't be relevant to client auth). Even if server does sent CertRequest that doesn't mean client will send Cert and CertVerify, nor does it mean server will treat client cert as required (it could be only requested/optional, depending on server and context). As a related option, if you can't install wireshark e.g. in production or remote, you can capture a pcap file with `tcpdump -w`, move it to a machine with wireshark and display it there.

Comment: Hi - sorry I was out for awhile due to injury/recovery - Can you all suggest the specific tcpdump command line that would capture information that could then be used to confirm whether or not there was 2-way SSL handshake occurring?  Oh also, I do control both client end and server end configurations.